# Using a list of variables in a loop

Tags: r, list, loops

I am working on testing if the list of strings firearm_char is found as a substrings in a list of variables that are in a dataframe. rather than writing out all these queries, I would like to loop through. How do I approach having the loop treat the var list as column names instead of strings?

```
cod_acme_raw_vars <-      c("ucod","acme1","acme2","acme3","acme4","acme5","acme6","acme7","acme8","acme9","acme10","acme11")
firearm_char <-c("W32","W33","W34","X72","X73","X74","X93","X94","X95","Y22","Y23","Y24","Y350","U014")

for (i in 1:length(cod_acme_raw_vars)) {
  for (j in 1:length(firearm_char)) {
    deaths16_21$all_firearm <- grepl( firearm_char[[j]] , cod_acme_raw_vars[[i]],)
  }
}
```

I have tried several functions to treat the variable list as field names including . data, as.name.

Thank you!
Robyn

Comment: Could you give more context around the data frame 'deaths16_21' and what is cod_acme_raw_vars for? What is your expected outcome for a sample?

Comment: Maybe you want `grepl(paste(firearm_char, collapse = "|"), cod_acme_raw_vars)` ?

Answer (score 1):

I am also unsure of what you're trying to accomplish exactly, but if you are trying to create a subset of the data frame by matching the values in your list, then you can do something like this with the `filter` function using `filter_all` from `library(dplyr)`.

```
A <- data.frame(ColumnOne = c("ucod","maybe","there","is","one"), 
                ColumnTwo = c("there", "W32","W33","W34", "are"))

cod_acme_raw_vars <- c("ucod","acme1","acme2","acme3","acme4","acme5","acme6",
                       "acme7","acme8","acme9","acme10","acme11")
firearm_char <-c("W32","W33","W34","X72","X73","X74","X93","X94",
                 "X95","Y22","Y23","Y24","Y350","U014")

AppendedList = append(cod_acme_raw_vars, firearm_char)

B <- A %>%
  filter_all(any_vars(. %in% AppendedList))
```

Since you want to check for all of the items in the list, you can append the lists together so that you only search from one list with all of the values. Data frame `B` becomes the subset of all the rows which match with the values in your lists.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to use the `match` as below

```r
 match(firearm_char,cod_acme_raw_vars)
```

this will help check the list of strings from `firearm_char` with the list of strings in `cod_acme_raw_vars`, if a match is found then a index position number will return

```r
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA 12
```

based on that position we can identify that string from `firearm_char` and use it further.

I am not clear with what you would like to accomplish